# Use regular expressions to find variables matching certain criteria

Tags: javascript, regex, expression, adobe, livecycle

I want to use regular expression in Notepad++ to find expressions as follows:

form1.subform[0].linestatus[1](https://regex101.com/r/yF2rS1/1).rawValue

or

form1.subform.linestatus[1](https://regex101.com/r/yF2rS1/1).rawValue

or, the general pattern is as follows (Adobe LiveCycle FormCalc expression):

element1.element2[index1].element3[index2].element4.element_n.propName

where the [index1] and [index2] are optional.

Also, the match should exclude the following (Adobe LiveCycle JavaScript expression):

xfa.resolveNode("form1.subform.linestatus[1](https://regex101.com/r/yF2rS1/1)").rawValue
xfa.resolveNode("form1.subform[0].linestatus[1](https://regex101.com/r/yF2rS1/1)").rawValue

Or the general pattern is (must not match the following):
  xfa.resolveNode("element1.element2[index1].element3[index2].element4").propName

where propName could be any of the following fixed names:
- rawValue
- access
- formattedValue
...etc.

The objective eventually is to be able to convert the the the from the first Syntax (FormCalc) to the second one (JavaScript) using find/replace.

Appreciate your help.

Note: so far, I was able to use this expression but not enough:

```
\b(?!xfa\.resolveNode\(\")([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\[([0-9]+)\])?\.)*rawValue
```

EDIT:
I think I found the solution but I am not sure why it is working. Check this:

```
(^|[\s(])(?!xfa\.resolveNode\(")(([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(\[[0-9]+\])?\.?)*)(\.rawValue)
```

and here is a working sample:

> https://regex101.com/r/nY9vT1/9

Appreciate it if someone could explain why it is working and if there is a better solution?

EDIT:
Here is a simplified regx. The last one was crashing in certain cases due to complexity:

```
Find:   (?:(^|[\s;(])(?!xfa\.resolveNode\(\".+\"\))((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\[\]]*))(\.(?:rawValue|access|fillColor)))
Replace:    \1xfa.resolveNode\("\2"\)\3
```

Check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yF2rS1/1).

Tarek

Comment: Check the last edit. I think I found the solution and your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Simplified the regx to prevent crashes due to infinit backtracking.