# Regex find/replace to add default attribute to object reference in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, adobe, converters, livecycle-designer

In Adobe LiveCycle FormCalc, if you use the following reference to an object:

```
form1.subform[3].appraiser_address12
```

... in JavaScript it means:

```
xfa.resolveNode("form1.subform[3].appraiser_address12").rawValue
```

So, the attribute rawValue is default, but in JavaScript there is no default.

How you can use regex in Notepad++ to do the above?

The bottom line, I want to match the as per the following criteria:

1- if the object reference is not enclosed in double quotations.

2- The object reference does not have the attribute reference to 'rawValue'.

Eventually, I want to convert the following:

```
form1.subform[3].appraiser_address12
```

to

```
form1.subform[3].appraiser_address12.rawValue
```

I found part of needed regular expression in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142272/use-regular-expressions-to-find-variables-matching-certain-criteria).

EDIT: I think I found the solution after getting help from "bobble bubble". Check this:

```
(?![a-zA-Z0-9\[\].]*(?:rawValue|presence|access))([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]*\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9\[\].]+)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

See solution [here](https://regex101.com/r/aD4wQ1/5).